# When describing something in the past in a paper, should we use the present tense or past tense?

Tags: tense, usage

The experiment in a paper usually has already happened. Should we use the present tense or past tense when writing about it?

> (1) In this **study**, there **are/were** 15 adults who **complete/completed** the test.

> (2) In this **paper**, there **are/were** 15 adults who **complete/completed** the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the past because you are describing the way the test was performed, which is an action finished in the past. However, because of its impact on the present, you could also say:

> In this study, (there are) 15 adults (who) ***have completed*** the test.

I put between parenthesis what you can omit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean that "In this study, there are 15 adults who completed the test" is ok, too?

Comment: Yes, that's fine too. But here the emphasis is less on the impact on the present than on the action itself.